# Including other JavaScript libraries in custom Power BI visual

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, powerbi

Could someone please explain how this is done? I want to use the d3 library but I don't know how to actually use it from within my visual.ts file. I've installed it with npm and added it to the externalJS part of pbiviz.json, is there anything else I need to configure before I can include and use it in visual.ts?

When I add `import * as d3 from "../node_modules/d3";` to the top of visual.ts then I get the following error:
[image]

I've also tried just `import * as d3 from "d3"`; to no avail.

I've looked through the source of the example custom visual ([here](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals-sampleBarChart)) but couldn't actually find any kind of importing/including... In barchart.ts they just start using d3 straight away, which is a bit confusing. When I try that I get:
[image]

Could someone please show me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/custom-visual-develop-tutorial) for a basic tutorial to develop custom visuals which uses D3.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install typings?:
There are draft of docs, how to install typings of d3 library by using npm
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/pull/186/files

or you can use old way to install typings by using typings utils:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Tutorial/Typings.md

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path to "externalJS" in pbiviz.json